# Maven Dependency problem - Missing artifacts

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am working with Eclipse on a Java project using Maven. In my `pom.xml` file I am getting the `**Missing artifact**` error with four different dependencies:

- `com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2`
- `es.ayelensolutions:commons-utils:jar:0.0.3-RELEASE`
- `es.ayelensolutions:gestionaclient:jar:0.1.16`
- `es.dipcas:framework:jar:0.0.46`

The dependencies are added to the `pom.xml` file, and I have tried to clean and update the project and so on, but I still get the same error with these dependencies. ¿Any idea?

Comment: Have you configured the relevant repositories? I guess these are not in MavenCentral.

Comment: I don't think **es.ayelensolutions** or **es.dipcas** are any group which creates/generates any jar file. So, please check if mentioned artifacts are correct. Moreover, check if repository from which you are fetching jars have these jars present there. If not, configure correct repository

Comment: These dependencies are not available in Maven central repository. If you know the repository which have these artifacts, then you can add the repository to your pom.xml.  You can find more information here. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Your answers helped me to understand and solve the problem.